# Add quota left to headers azure apimanager

Tags: xml, azure-api-management, quota

For a project that we are working on, we are using azure apimanager to manage our subscriptions and products.

We have the following policy setup for a subscription:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <quota-by-key calls="3" renewal-period="0" counter-key="@(context.Subscription?.Key ?? "anonymous")" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 200 && context.Response.StatusCode < 300)"/>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <set-header name="quota-left" exists-action="append">
            <value>{AMOUNT OF CALLS LEFT}</value>
        </set-header>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Can I, and if so how, set a header value for the amount of calls left in the quota of the subscription?

I tried googling but Azure doesnt seem to have a clear way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that automatically through the runtime, but you can use the below rest api by building another api management api on top of that rest api to return how many calls has been made for a specific quota window for a specific key. Below document explains how to use it and what data it returns.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/quota-by-counter-keys